When setting up on testnet, "Error: airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached."
After generating keypairs locally and moving to the airdrop step I’m getting this error: "Error: airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached." I do have 1 sol it shows, but on mainnet. I funded it myself and am wondering could that be the issue. I did originally setup with. Window’s terminal but even tried in bash to airdrop and still nothing. How do I fix? Thanks ahead for any help!

This has nothing with mainnet-beta SOL being in your wallet (I would discourage you from keeping mainnet SOL in your testing wallet).
It means that you have been rate-limited and cannot request devnet airdrop from your solana CLI.
alternatives testnet sol sources

https://faucet.solana.com/

https://solfaucet.com/

https://faucet.quicknode.com/solana/devnet

You can sign up for the helius RPC free tier and request airdrop from the dashboard.

https://www.testnetfaucet.org/

Alternatively, wait till tomorrow and request from the CLI


ref: https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/solana-token-airdrop-and-faucets

Thanks, I ended up just getting new keys and it worked.
